# Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed FireStore

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I try to create a custom import command for large JSON file based on this one: https://github.com/codediodeio/firestore-migrator

But I have facing the following issue on my custom command:

```
(node:19413) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed.
    at WriteBatch.verifyNotCommitted (/Users/mac-clement/Documents/projets/dpas/gcp/import-data/csv-import/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:116:19)
    at WriteBatch.set (/Users/mac-clement/Documents/projets/dpas/gcp/import-data/csv-import/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:234:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mac-clement/Documents/projets/dpas/gcp/import-data/csv-import/dist/src/importJson.js:90:17)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/mac-clement/Documents/projets/dpas/gcp/import-data/csv-import/dist/src/importJson.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/mac-clement/Documents/projets/dpas/gcp/import-data/csv-import/dist/src/importJson.js:3:12)
    at batchSet (/Users/mac-clement/Documents/projets/dpas/gcp/import-data/csv-import/dist/src/importJson.js:85:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mac-clement/Documents/projets/dpas/gcp/import-data/csv-import/dist/src/importJson.js:74:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
(node:19413) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 174)
```

It's probably a promise issue because a new batch is set in the batchCommit function ... but I am struggling finding it ! Thanks for your help !

```js
/**
 * Dependencies
 */
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as fs from "file-system";
import * as _ from "lodash";
import {streamArray} from "stream-json/streamers/StreamArray";
import {parser} from "stream-json";

/**
 * Global variables
 */
let args;
let db = admin.firestore();
let batch = db.batch();
let batchCount = 0;
let totalSetCount = 0;

/**
 * Main function
 *
 * @param file
 * @param collection
 * @param options
 */
export const execute = (file: string, collection: string, options) => {
  args = options;
  if( args.dryRun ) args.verbose = true;

  console.log('Importing data...');
  console.log('File path: ' + file);
  console.log('Collection: ' + collection);
  console.log('Limit: ' + args.limit);
  console.log('Chunk: ' + args.chunk);

  return fs.createReadStream(file)
    .pipe(parser())
    .pipe(streamArray())
    .on('data', async (row) => {
      await Promise.resolve(manageRow(row.value, collection));
    })
    .on('end', async () => {
      // Final Batch commit and completion message.
      await batchCommit(false);
      console.log(args.dryRun
        ? 'Dry-Run complete, Firestore was not updated.'
        : 'Import success, Firestore updated!'
      );
      console.log(`Total documents written: ${totalSetCount}`);
    });
}

/**
 *
 * @param row
 * @param collection
 */
const manageRow = async (row: object, collection: string) => {
  const colRef = db.collection(collection);

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    for (let [id, item] of Object.entries(row)) {
      const docRef = colRef.doc(id);
      await batchSet(docRef, item);
    }
    resolve();
  });
}

/**
 * Add an item in the batch and call commit if batch size reached chunk
 *
 * @param ref
 * @param item
 */
const batchSet = async (ref: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference, item: object) => {
  // Log if requested
  args.verbose && console.log(`Writing: ${ref.path}`);    

  // Set the Document Data
  ++totalSetCount;
  await batch.set(ref, item);

  // Commit batch on chunk size
  if (++batchCount % args.chunk === 0) {
    await batchCommit();
  }
}

/**
 * Commit changes to FireStore database and initialize a new batch if recycle is set to true
 *
 * @param recycle
 */
const batchCommit = async (recycle: boolean = true) => {
  // Nothing to commit or dry run so do not commit
  if (!batchCount || args.dryRun) return;

  // Log if requested
  args.verbose && console.log(batchCount + ' documents have been written so long ...');

  await batch.commit();

  if(recycle) {
    batch = db.batch();
    batchCount = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to reuse a batch object for multiple commits.  This is not valid.  Create a new batch object for each commit.

Comment: It should be assigning a new batch in the batchCommit function with the recycle parameters.

Comment: Very that with some debug logging.